# R Shiny--Error in as.POSIXlt.default: do not know how to convert 'x' to class “POSIXlt”

Tags: r, shiny

Here I want to write an app to calculate bond schedule and show it in a table. But the following problems always appear in error and I don't know how to solve them.

Error Message:Warning: Error in as.POSIXlt.default: do not know how to convert 'x' to class “POSIXlt”. Warning: Error in rep: attempt to replicate an object of type 'closure'

Below is my code. Thank you!!

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
library(lubridate)

ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel("This is a Bond Calculator"),
        mainPanel("Suppose par value is $100")
    )),
    dateInput("sd", "Start Date", Sys.Date()),
    numericInput("t", "Tenor(in year)", 0.5),
    numericInput("r", "Coupon Rate", 0.05),
    numericInput("freq", "Coupon Frequency", 10),
    numericInput("ytm", "Yield To Maturity",0.05),
    #plotOutput("p1"),
    tableOutput("dt1")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
        
        coupon <- reactiveVal(0)
        observeEvent(input$r, coupon(100*(input$r)*(input$t)))
        
        npv <- reactiveVal(0)            
        calc_npv <- function(){
            sum <- 0
            for(i in 0:input$freq)
                sum <- sum + coupon()/(1+ytm*input$t)^(i*input$t)
            npv(sum)
        }
        
        cnt <- reactiveVal(0) 
        observeEvent(input$freq, cnt(seq(1,input$freq)))
        
        temp <- reactiveVal(0)   #construct payment dates
        observeEvent(input$sd, temp(rep(input$sd,input$freq)))
        observeEvent(input$freq, temp(rep(input$sd,input$freq)))
        pd <- reactiveVal(0)
        observeEvent(pd, pd(month(temp())+cnt()*12))  #add the tenor respectively
        observeEvent(cnt, pd(month(temp())+cnt()*12))
        
        payment <- reactiveVal(0)   #construct payments
        observeEvent(payment(input$freq), payment(c(rep(coupon(),input$freq-1),coupon()+100))) #1 to freq-1 combined with the last payment
        
        df <- reactiveVal(0)
        observeEvent(pd, df(tibble(Date = pd(), Payment = payment())))
        observeEvent(payment, df(tibble(Date = pd(), Payment = payment())))

        #output$p1 <- renderPlot({
            
        #})
        output$dt1 <- renderDataTable(df(), options = list(pageLength = 5))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: `rep(coupon(), ...)` for your second error (since `coupon` is a reactive value, it appears like a function ... which is occasionally referenced as `closure` in R errors). Also, your `function` is broken in this same way. (Functions included in a shiny app should *not* try to access reactive values or such themselves.)

Comment: I missed some ... there are several references to `coupon`, all of them (except the instantiation as a `reactiveVal`) should use `coupon()`.

Comment: ah yup. Thanks a lot! Here is no error but the output is nothing. The new version of my code is edited in the original post above

Comment: Try `dataTableOutput("dt1")` in your `ui` instead of `tableOutput` since you use `renderDataTable` in `server`.

Comment: alright! thanks to all